# Encoding format while writing word document using Apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am creating a word document using Apache POI API. I am reading a text file and writing that text to word document.

Is there any way that while writing text, the encoding format can be specified as UTF-8. While writing the document I am loosing the space and tabs read from Text file. I think probably the encoding format differs due to which the spaces, tab etc are getting lost in document.

Comment: Are you telling Apache POI about the spaces and tabs properly? XML formats like Word `.docx` normally ignore whitespace in text